# Jquery slide out with an adjacent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

If you look [to the right side of this page](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons) you'll see what I'm talking about.

Basically, when you click on that little "Tag this Picture/Submit Picture", I want a it to slide out along with a previously hidden div to the right of it. I kind of have that working right now, but as you can see the part you click just jumps over to the ending point instead of being "pushed" out by the new panel sliding out, which is what I want it do do.

Here's the Jquery I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#right_new").click(function(){
        $("#right_panel").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);

        });

        });
</script>
```

If anyone can help me implement a toggle part of it, that would be awesome too, but what I really need for now is just the slide part to work well. I can probably figure out the if/then part for that eventually.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need any additional info!

Comment: Try using jQuery animation: .animate({ marginRight: 0 }); // the default margin should be a negative number, maybe -300px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#right_new").click(function(){
          $("#right_side_container").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);

        });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track! However, the container isn't hidden, but the panel part it is containing is. Is there any way to unhide the panel and then move the container over?

Comment: I got it. Used `$("#right_panel").show();` All I need now is the cancel option to slide it back. Thanks for all the help. I'll select yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your icons are popping out before the slide is happening, is b/c you are hiding the `#right_panel`, then displaying with the `.show()` command, will now it's occupying space in the dom and pushing your item to the left.

What I like to do is animate the whole block in and out using the position:absolute;

Take a look at these CSS and JS changes http://jsfiddle.net/rtgibbons/jDThJ/ (note: this slides it in and out)

I'm using the `.animate({right: '' })` to move the entire container left and right.

Comment: This actually moves smoother than what I had. However, I'm having some problems with the scrolling part of it. Before you click and slide the panel in, the bottom (left/right) scroll bar is visible and when you scroll over you can see the panel. How do I make it "invisible" and get rid of the possibility to scroll over and see it? Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: I noticed it in jsfiddle, but chalked it up to the layout of jsfiddle. Looking at your site I don't see the scroll bars. what you could do is set the `overflow:hidden` on a parent element. Maybe even the body?

Comment: Sorry I'm late to getting back to you. But I eventually just set it to `overflow-x: hidden` like you suggested. Should've updated here. Thanks for all the help though! It works great.